# What is the best food to eat at this type of day since it is so vey very late?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, homework

Best food to eat? In this time of the day because it's late very soon to be

Comment: Welcome to Biology. It's 20:15 in my time zone, and in the West Coast in the US it's still morning. So be specific. Further, this question may be opinion based and even if it's not, it's better suited for Health. SE. Could you improve your question such that it is clear what you define as 'late' and consider the fact that the question should be answered in a scientific fashion without a medical advice component?

Comment: Following AliceD, it is currently 1:35pm where I live. Also, note that [The dose makes the poison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dose_makes_the_poison) and therefore nothing is fundamentally healthy, everything is toxic, it just depends upon your needs (and therefore a lot on a standard diet). Also, "Best" is very subjective. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If this question relates to evolution then everything on this website really does.

Comment: @Remi.b - If by evolution, you mean the physiology all biological organisms evolved, their genetic and environmentally adapted behaviors, etc,. then yes, it probably all does.